# I can't get G29 to run BLTouch on my Ender 3 V2

Tags: creality-ender-3, g-code, bed-leveling, bltouch

I installed a BLTouch probe on my Ender 3 V2 and am able to manually generate the probe matrix and store it in the printer memory, but I can't figure out how to get Cura to run the probe for every print. I have included `G29` in my start code, but the printer doesn't run the probe. Here is my full start code:

```
M201 X500.00 Y500.00 Z100.00 E5000.00 ;Setup machine max acceleration
M203 X500.00 Y500.00 Z10.00 E50.00 ;Setup machine max feedrate
M204 P500.00 R1000.00 T500.00 ;Setup Print/Retract/Travel acceleration
M205 X8.00 Y8.00 Z0.40 E5.00 ;Setup Jerk
M220 S100 ;Reset Feedrate
M221 S100 ;Reset Flowrate

G28 ;Home

G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder

G29 ;BLTouch

G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
G1 X10.1 Y20 Z0.28 F5000.0 ;Move to start position
G1 X10.1 Y200.0 Z0.28 F1500.0 E15 ;Draw the first line
G1 X10.4 Y200.0 Z0.28 F5000.0 ;Move to side a little
G1 X10.4 Y20 Z0.28 F1500.0 E30 ;Draw the second line
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ;Move Z Axis up
```

When I inspect the G-code directly, I can see that `G29` is getting transpiled into

```
M501 ;load bed level data
M420 S1 ;enable bed leveling
```

is this correct? If not, how do I stop the transpilation?

Comment: Dear Matthew, could you please provide some more information on the installation of the BLTouch and the configuration/installation of the firmware.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a firmware issue to me. I copied and pasted

```
G28 ;Home
G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder
G29 ;BLTouch
```

Into my start code, and it worked fine.
I have an Ender 3 V2 and a BLTouch (BL, not 3D.)
If you haven't updated your firmware, that's definitely why.

This is the start code I am using (in Ultimaker Cura)

```
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
G29 ; Auto bed level
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X5 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move over to prevent blob squish
```

---

*How are you manually initiating the bed level? G-code command? (If so, which command/commands) or on the printer itself?*

*If you haven't already, I suggest you try placing the line `G92 E0 ;Reset Extruder` before the line `G28 ;Home`. I'm wondering if it is possible that this is somehow interrupting the process.*

*Are you on stock firmware? If so, I would try using firmware for the BLTouch, from [the manufacturer](https://forums.creality3dofficial.com/download/ender-series/ender-3-v2/).*

*You can find a guide on how to do a firmware update [here is an external link](https://all3dp.com/2/ender-3-v2-firmware-update/).

*You shouldn't have to change anything in the configuration if you download the pre-configured BLTouch firmware.*

Comment: Hi Void_Frost! Thank you for your efforts to help, they're good and accurate hints. I am curious about the real cause too. Please note that your response is actually questions, suggesting the real answer or troubleshooting path (like executing the `G29` command manually from serial terminal). Could you try to reformulate this response to be an actual answer (i.e. try this, do this, etc.)? If you like to ask more questions, better to use comments below main description. Btw. I bet for firmware configuration, could you advice something to start from? Check [here about G-code queuing](/q/15228/).

Comment: Right. Thanks for the advice. I'm new to 3d printing (got my printer last month), stack exchange, and this in general.

Comment: @Void_Frost No problem, we all were new once, but this is a Q/A answer site not a forum of threaded messages, questions to clarify the question need to be in comments, once you receive 50 reputation you can comment on questions for more information. Hope to see you around! I've rearranged the answer a little so that it is more of an answer. Considering your relative short experience, you might want to [ask](/questions/ask) some questions. Happy printing!

Comment: @0scar I noticed you put a guide on how to install firmware here on 3D stack exchange, and while I appreciate it, I removed it as it does NOT apply to this model of 3D printer. Firmware updates are not in .hex, rather in .bin, and are handled via microSD.

Comment: @Void_Frost No prob! Thanks for the edit! You must have the newer controller board. :-)